# Accessing the nested div with same class names but different test using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to iterate through the div structure.Actually, what I want is if I have different div structures with same class name e.g. mod and I want to check the internal div whose class name is title. The only difference between them are the contents of the div with class name title have text as hello1 and for other its hello2.

Here is the Structure

```
<div class="mod" id="mod23" >
      <div class="content" >
       <div class="hd" >
         <div class="title">Hello1</div>
           <ul class="list"></ul>
           <ul class="buttons">
             <li class="help"></li>
             <li class="show" ></li>
             <li class="close"></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="mod" id="mod27" >
      <div class="content" >
       <div class="hd" >
         <div class="title">Hello2</div>
           <ul class="list"></ul>
           <ul class="buttons">
             <li class="help"></li>
             <li class="show" ></li>
             <li class="close"></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Here is the code I have tried to come up with which is not working

```
$('div').each(function(index) {
if($(this).hasClass('title').text('Hello1')){
    alert('found');
    }
});
```

Comment: you can give more than one class name to an element, just seperate them by a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `contains` selector:

```
$('div.title:contains("Hello")').each(function(index) {
    alert('found');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/atayeb/2/

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = $('div.title').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Hello1";
});

// Do something with result
```

Or you can look at the [contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) but this does match everything witch matches your query.

```
var result = $('div.title:contains(Hello1)')
```

---

To check if you match anything simply:

```
if ( result.length ) {
    alert("found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').each(function(index) {
if($(this).find('.title').first().text() == 'Hello1'){
    alert('found');
    }
});
```

there might be cooler ways though

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
<script>
$('div').each(function(index) {
if($(this).hasClass('title') && $(this).text() == 'Hello1'){
    alert('found');
    }
});
</script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can get to the `div` you are interested in more directly by using a [CSS selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
$('.mod .title').each(function(i, e) {  
    if($(e).text() == 'Hello1') {
        alert('found');
    }
});?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('div').each(function (index) {
        if ($(".title")) {
            if ($(this).text('Hello1')) {
                alert('found');
            }
        }
    });
```